# ActiveRecord How to combine two conditions on a where with a join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables with a join table in between:

Series

```
  create_table "series", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  class Series < ApplicationRecord
    include PgSearch::Model

    has_many :makers
    has_many :creators, through: :makers
    has_many :sources, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :entries, through: :sources

    validates :title, presence: true

    pg_search_scope :search_by_title, against: {
      title: 'A',
      title_en: 'B',
      title_en_jp: 'C'
    }
  end
```

Maker

```
  create_table "makers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "series_id", null: false
    t.bigint "creator_id", null: false
    t.bigint "creator_type", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["creator_id"], name: "index_makers_on_creator_id"
    t.index ["series_id", "creator_id", "creator_type"], name: "index_makers_on_series_and_creator_and_type", unique: true
    t.index ["series_id"], name: "index_makers_on_series_id"
  end

  # frozen_string_literal: true

  class Maker < ApplicationRecord
    extend Enumerize

    belongs_to :series
    belongs_to :creator

    validates :series, uniqueness: { scope: %i[creator creator_type] }

    enumerize :creator_type, in: {
      author: 1,
      artist: 2
    }, predicates: true, scope: true
  end
```

Creator

```
  create_table "creators", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_creators_on_name"
  end

  class Creator < ApplicationRecord
    include PgSearch::Model

    has_many :makers
    has_many :series, through: :makers

    pg_search_scope :search_by_title, against: :name
  end
```

Based on the tables above, I wanted to create a `where` method, which would find `Series` for specific makers. The issue is for series that have two makers, usually an `author` and `artist`.

So while this code works, to find a `Series` for a specific creator:

```rb
  def self.find_by_creators(title, creators)
    where(title: title)
      .joins(makers: :creator)
      .where(
        makers: {
          creator_type: :author,
          creators: { name: creators[:authors] }
        }
      )
  end
```

when trying to add another `where`, nothing gets returned:

```rb
  def self.find_by_creators(title, creators)
    where(title: title)
      .joins(makers: :creator)
      .where(
        makers: {
          creator_type: :author,
          creators: { name: creators[:authors] }
        }
      )
      .where(
        makers: {
          creator_type: :artist,
          creators: { name: creators[:artists] }
        }
      )
  end
```

Comment: Chaining where would create AND condition so that unlikely match records. Use OR.Checkout https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/30/rails-5-adds-or-support-in-active-record.html

Comment: @AmitPatel Well, I do need an AND condition, not an OR. I want a record, that contains exactly the author and artist I am looking for. I don't want to get a record back, that matches the author, but not the artist. And vice versa

Comment: Append `to_sql` to your query and check if it gets you result in your db client? Check if the generated query is what you are expecting?

Comment: Also please show your three models. Are you sure you have all your associations correct?

Comment: @Beartech I have added my models. Associations work, I can retrieve this data by doing separate queries, but not when I try to combine them

Comment: Just to sanity check, I would try it using a SQL fragment like: `def self.find_by_creators(title, creators)
    where(title: title)
      .joins(makers: :creator)
      .where(
        "(makers.creator_type = ? AND creators.name = ?)
        AND
         (makers.creator_type = ? AND creators.name = ?)",
            :author, creators[:authors], :artist, creators[:artists] )
end`

Comment: Also, is it possible that and artist and an author might work on more than one series together?  Are you expecting to return only one result every time?

Comment: This is the generated SQL, using fragment you provided: `Series Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "series".* FROM "series" INNER JOIN "makers" ON "makers"."series_id" = "series"."id" INNER JOIN "creators" ON "creators"."id" = "makers"."creator_id" WHERE "series"."title" = $1 AND ((makers.creator_type = 1 AND creators.name = 'Park Saenal') AND (makers.creator_type = 2 AND creators.name = 'Yoon Jun')) LIMIT $2  [["title", "Overgeared"], ["LIMIT", 11]]`

And yes, it is possible that the same artist and author could have other series assigned to them. Not in this example though.

Comment: My testcase is: There are two series, with identical titles. So I need to find the one, with specific artist and author